# Is this what Rails resources is meant to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Instead of adding all of this to the routes.rb:

```
  #get 'todos' => 'todos#index'
  #get 'todos/new' => 'todos#new'
  #post 'todos' => 'todos#create'
```

Are Rails `resources` meant to compress the above into this?

```
resources :todos
```

Plus you also get `edit` and `destroy`?

Is there any reason not to use `resources` in this case?

Comment: In this case, there's no reason not to use resources.

Comment: Why not? Looks perfectly legitimate use case to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is what resources is all about.
Under the hood it is creating this gets, posts etc

In addition You can pass in options to resources:

- **:only**
- **:except**

to create mappings for given actions.

```
resources :todos, only: [:new]
resources :todos, except: [:edit, :show]
```

So in your case you can do:

```
resources :todos, only: [:index, :new, :create]
```

Additionally the singular version can be used:

```
resource :todo #except and only still apply
```

This will create all standard CRUD mappings apart of index one.
It can be used when you don't really need ID part of the resource.

I tend to always use resources/resource even if I only need a single action it make routes file much more readable.

[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

A resource creates 7 different routes:

`resources :photos`

- `GET  /photos photos#index`
- `GET  /photos/new photos#new`
- `POST /photos photos#create`
- `GET  /photos/:id photos#show`
- `GET  /photos/:id/edit    photos#edit`
- `PATCH/PUT    /photos/:id photos#update`
- `DELETE   /photos/:id photos#destroy`

You can also use `:only` and `:except` to decide which of those 7 options you want to use.

`resources :photos, only: [:index]`

- `GET  /photos photos#index`

`resources :photos, except: [:index]`

- `GET  /photos/new photos#new`
- `POST /photos photos#create`
- `GET  /photos/:id photos#show`
- `GET  /photos/:id/edit    photos#edit`
- `PATCH/PUT    /photos/:id photos#update`
- `DELETE   /photos/:id photos#destroy`

[Here is a detailed explanation from the Rails website](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

[`resources :controller` is just a helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

> Resource routing allows you to quickly declare all of the common routes for a given resourceful controller. Instead of declaring separate routes for your `index`, `show`, `new`, `edit`, `create`, `update` and `destroy` actions, a resourceful route declares them in a single line of code.

Controllers are meant to be "resourceful" (more explained in a second). Thus, Rails handily creates the following routes when you declare `resources :controller` -

```
GET         /photos             photos#index      display a list of all photos
GET         /photos/new         photos#new        return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST        /photos             photos#create     create a new photo
GET         /photos/:id         photos#show       display a specific photo
GET         /photos/:id/edit    photos#edit       return an HTML form for editing a photo
PATCH/PUT   /photos/:id         photos#update     update a specific photo
DELETE      /photos/:id         photos#destroy    delete a specific photo
```

This gives you the resourceful actions required for use in a "complete" controller.

If you don't need to use all of these, there are options you can pass to the helper to give you only specific routes, namely [`only:` & `except:`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :todos, only: [:new, :index, :create]
```

There are several [other options](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments) you can pass -

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :tasks, as: :todos, controller: :todos, path: "todo_list", path_names: { new: "add", create: "add", index: "all" }, only: [:new, :index, :create]
```

You can also pass a block to the helper to [add extra routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :todos, except: :destroy do
   get :today, on: :collection
end
```

So in that sense, it's *highly* advisable you use `resources`, even if you don't employ all the routes it provides. If anything, it keeps your routes structured and simply maintained.

--

The reason why Rails has the `resorce` method is to provide a set of *resourceful* actions / urls.

From the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

> Browsers request pages from Rails by making a request for a URL using a specific HTTP method, such as GET, POST, PATCH, PUT and DELETE. Each method is a request to perform an operation on the resource. A resource route maps a number of related requests to actions in a single controller.

This is part of a much larger specification, [defined in HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_resource#From_documents_and_files_to_web_resources):

> In the early specifications of the web (1990–1994), the term resource is barely used at all. The web is designed as a network of more or less static addressable objects, basically files and documents, linked using uniform resource locators (URLs). A web resource is implicitly defined as something which can be identified

In our interpretation, where `objects` can be anything from a link to an `iOS` app, to a file, Rails has a set of routes which provide us with the ability to manage the objects on our servers.